# Why does Vagrant-defined networking have no effect?

Tags: networking, fedora, virtualbox, ifconfig, vagrant

I'm attempting to provision two VM's that can send traffic to each other, but I am having trouble implementing this with Vagrant. In my `Vagrantfile` I have:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "base"

  config.vm.define "machine_a" do |machine_a|
    machine_a.vm.box = "fedora/36-cloud-base"
    machine_a.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
    machine_a.vm.hostname = "machine-a"
    machine_a.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.memory = "2048"
    end
  end

  config.vm.define "machine_b" do |machine_b|
    machine_b.vm.box = "fedora/36-cloud-base"
    machine_b.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.11"
    machine_b.vm.hostname = "machine-b"
    machine_b.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.memory = "2048"
    end
  end

end
```

However, when I run `ifconfig` in the **machine_a** VM, I get:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::c108:7157:9132:af74  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 52:54:00:56:a8:b4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1063  bytes 120984 (118.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 976  bytes 141524 (138.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.56.110  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255
        inet6 fe80::a92f:2b09:ddc3:1fa2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:72:bd:cf  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 48  bytes 15724 (15.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 38  bytes 3474 (3.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 8  bytes 648 (648.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8  bytes 648 (648.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Unless I'm missing something, there is neither a reference to the machine_b on this private network, nor is there any reference to the two IP's I had specified in the `Vagrantfile` (`192.168.33.10` or `192.168.33.11`).

Any guidance on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar problem. My problem variant is that the guest gets a 172.16.-address automatically from Vagrant, and my private IP-address definitions does not show up in *nmcli* on the built up box.

One workaround I found: if I change the box to be based on `generic/centos9s` both eth-interfaces gets an IP address.

Do you have a `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth?` file for the problematic interfaces? I have, but somehow it doesn't get "picked" up by the system/nmcli/whatnot.